# How to fix Bottom Over flow when only some section of screen is scrollable

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an image carousel on top and want only the bottom part of the screen/page to scroll, but keep getting bottom overflow. how do i fix this... please!?

I have tried ListView at different places aswell as SingleChildScrollView but to no avail.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:homenet/pages/search_page.dart';
import 'package:system_shortcuts/system_shortcuts.dart';

class PropertyDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final propertyDetailImage;
  final propertyDetailTown;
  final propertyDetailArea;
  final propertyDetailStatus;
  final propertyDetailPrice;

  PropertyDetails(
      {this.propertyDetailImage,
      this.propertyDetailTown,
      this.propertyDetailArea,
      this.propertyDetailStatus,
      this.propertyDetailPrice}); @override
  _PropertyDetailsState createState() => _PropertyDetailsState();
}

class _PropertyDetailsState extends State<PropertyDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    ========  CAROUSEL  =========
    Widget imageSlider = Container(
      height: 200,
      child: Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
        images: [
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house1.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house2.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house3.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house4.jpg'),
        ],
        autoplay: false,
        dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
        dotSize: 0,
      ),
    );

    final banner = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 160.0, left: 4.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFFA983A).withOpacity(.75),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
          ),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Text(
          "For Sale",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );

//    ========  CAROUSEL  =========
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFFA983A),
        title: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/logo_white.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SearchPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            height: 200,
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Hero(
                tag: 'carouselHero',
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      imageSlider,
                      banner,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onDoubleTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                  return ImageScreen();
                }));
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 4),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, top: 4.0, right: 12.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "Rehoboth",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Ref: RBD02548649",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "236 Block D",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "N$ 550,000.00,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                color: Color(0xFFFA983A)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 8,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/icons/beds_new.png',
                                scale: 1.75,
                              ),
                              Text(" 4"),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 8,
                              ),
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/icons/bath_new.png',
                                scale: 1.75,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                " 3",
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 8,
                              ),
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/icons/parking_new.png',
                                scale: 1.75,
                              ),
                              Text(" 2"),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "1200 sqr ft.",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
//            PROPERTY DESCRIPTION ==============================
                      Text(
                        'Description',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting "
                        "industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy "
                        "text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a "
                        "galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. "
                        "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap "
                        "into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      Divider(height: 10),
                      Text(
                        "AMENITIES",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
//            AMENITIES STARTS HERE ===============================
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Home Loan Calculator",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                        Image.asset("assets/google_map.jpg"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want to add as much content as i want without the overflow at the the bottom. Please help me in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: Please, place a reproducible code here.

Comment: @HugoPassos I hope this is inorder. thank you...

Comment: It's not. I still don't have `PropertyDetails`, just its state.

Comment: @HugoPassos thats all of it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, my problem was that i had everything wrapped in a Column which only has its screen size height and not scrollable beyond that giving overflow if the content is to much. body: is a column with a container for the Carousel. Then outside of that Everything is wrapped in a Flexible -> ListView -> Container -> columns and then Rows For the different styling and positioning of content.