# How to change the orientation of on page in my app

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to change the orientation of only one page within my app to landscape to view larger pictures

I can only find code to set orientation for the whole app. I don't know how to implement this( [Flutter: How to set and lock screen orientation on-demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322054/flutter-how-to-set-and-lock-screen-orientation-on-demand) ) code into the existing code

````
//    ========  CAROUSEL  =========
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFFA983A),
        title: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/logo_white.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SearchPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            height: 200,
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Hero(
                tag: 'carouselHero',
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      imageSlider,
                      banner,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onDoubleTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                  return ImageScreen();
                }));
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 4),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, top: 4.0, right: 12.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            widget.propertyDetailTown,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Ref: RBD02548649",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            widget.propertyDetailArea,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            widget.propertyDetailPrice,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                color: Color(0xFFFA983A)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 8,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/icons/beds_new.png',
                                scale: 1.75,
                              ),
                              Text(" 4"),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 8,
                              ),
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/icons/bath_new.png',
                                scale: 1.75,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                " 3",
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 8,
                              ),
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/icons/parking_new.png',
                                scale: 1.75,
                              ),
                              Text(" 2"),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "1200 sqr ft.",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
//            PROPERTY DESCRIPTION ==============================
                      Text(
                        'Description',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting "
                        "industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy "
                        "text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a "
                        "galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. "
                        "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap "
                        "into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      Divider(height: 10),
                      Text(
                        "AMENITIES",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
//            AMENITIES STARTS HERE ===============================
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.hotel,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "  One",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 100.0),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.room,
                            color: Color(0xFFFA983A),
                          ),
                          Text("  Two")
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Home Loan Calculator",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),

//                        Image.asset("assets/google_map.jpg"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
//    ===========SECOND PAGE NEEDS TO BE LANDSCAPE ==================
class ImageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget imageSlider = Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
        images: [
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house1.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house2.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house3.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house4.jpg'),
        ],
        autoplay: false,
        dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
        dotSize: 0,

      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'carouselHero',
            child: imageSlider,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}```

when i click on a picture it has to go to a new page which automatically change orientation to Landscape ans when i click back to previous page it changes again.
````

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322054/flutter-how-to-set-and-lock-screen-orientation-on-demand

Comment: Thank you @HugoPassos but its doesn't seem to work of maybe I'm adding the code in the wrong place...?

Comment: The question is duplicated, please see the provided answer.

Comment: @Hosar yes but how do i implement it...? Please see the code i provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `StatelessWidget`, so you cannot override `initState` and `dispose`. First, convert your `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget`, then implement the code provided by the other answer.

```dart
class ImageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ImageScreenState createState() => ImageScreenState();
}

class ImageScreenState extends State<ImageScreen> {
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  dispose(){
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget imageSlider = Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
        images: [
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house1.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house2.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house3.jpg'),
          AssetImage('assets/images/houses/house4.jpg'),
        ],
        autoplay: false,
        dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
        dotSize: 0,

      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'carouselHero',
            child: imageSlider,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @HugoPassos highly appreciated. Can you give me advice on what to do with my bottom overflow on the first page.. already added SingleChildScrollView but if i add content it overflows.

Comment: If my answer works for you, please mark it as correct. I cannot run your code to check what causes the overflow, since there's a lot of unknown variables, like `imageSlider` and `widget.propertyDetailArea`. Please edit your question with a reproducible code.

Comment: please excuse I'm still new to all this but mark your answer now. ```ImageSlide``` is just the carousel widget in a 200 high container and ```widget.propertyDetails``` is just one of the getters for my json file. the area after carousel is scralable but if i add more content it overflows. thank you again for your help

Comment: so its basically from the ```expanded``` that i want it to be scrollable with as much content as needed. the ```widget.propertyDetailPrice``` can be replaced with any text...

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry but I cannot waste a lot of time with this. If you could edit your question with a reproducible code, I would be glad to help you. Actually, you are supposed to make another question. I can't mix two different answers into one question.

Comment: i already did here is the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146984/how-to-fix-bottom-over-flow-when-only-some-section-of-screen-is-scrollable